# What is significance of the Oozie MR launcher?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I created a simple Oozie work flow with Sqoop, Hive and Pig actions. For each of there actions, Oozie launches a MR launcher and which in turn launches the action (Sqoop/Hive/Pig). So, there are a total of 6 MR jobs for 3 actions in the work flow.

Why does Oozie start an MR launcher to start the action and not directly start the action?

Answer (score 4):

I posted the same in Apache Flume forums and here is the response.

> It's also to keep the Oozie server from being bogged down or becoming
>   unstable.  For example, if you have a bunch of workflows running Pig jobs,
>   then you'd have the Oozie server running multiple copies of the Pig client
>   (which is a relatively "heavy" program) directly.  By moving all of the
>   user code and external clients to map tasks in the launcher job, the Oozie
>   server remains more light-weight and less prone to errors.  It can also
>   much more scalable this way because the launcher jobs distribute the the
>   job launching/monitoring to other machines in the cluster; otherwise, with
>   the Oozie server doing everything, we'd have to limit the number of
>   concurrent workflows based on your Oozie server's machine specs (RAM, CPU,
>   etc).  And finally, from an architectural standpoint, the Oozie server
>   itself is stateless; that is, everything is stored in the database and the
>   Oozie server can be taken down at any point without losing anything.  If we
>   were to launch jobs directly from the Oozie server, then we'd now have some
>   state (e.g. the Pig client cannot be restarted and resumed).